# Convert HTML to plain text while preserving the exact locations of divisions

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried all current html to text conversion tools like html2text, beautifulsoup.  While converting html to text they lose the location of div boxes and print the text sequentially.

For html code for like this

```
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:107px; top:372px; width:89px; height:126px;"><span style="font-family: b\'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\'; font-size:15px">

<br>Location :
<br>Date:
<br>Date_Assigned:
<br>Date_Inspected:
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:215px; top:375px; width:248px; height:140px;"><span style="font-family: b\'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\'; font-size:15px">
<br>USA
<br>July 4, 2018
<br>July 5, 2018
<br>July 9, 2018
```

Plain Text output that I get from  beautifulsoup's get_text() is  like this

```
Location : Date: Date_Assigned:Date_Inspected:USA July 4, 2018July 5, 2018July 9, 2018
```

From html2text, the output looks like this

```
Location :  
Date:  
Date_Assigned:  
Date_Inspected:


USA  
July 4, 2018  
July 5, 2018  
July 9, 2018
```

While the expected output if you take into account of location of two div is

```html
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:107px; top:2px; width:89px; height:126px;"><span style="font-family: b\'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\'; font-size:15px">

<br>Location :
<br>Date:
<br>Date_Assigned:
<br>Date_Inspected:
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:215px; top:2px; width:248px; height:140px;"><span style="font-family: b\'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\'; font-size:15px">
<br>USA
<br>July 4, 2018
<br>July 5, 2018
<br>July 9, 2018
```

Is it possible to convert to text preserving the location of div using beautiful soup or any other python packages available?

Comment: What the tool is outputting is a literal conversion of your HTML to text. The "text alignment" is an artifact of CSS. I suggest a more semantic use of HTML if possible.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to create a script that converts it correctly for you? Or how to style the given output to fit the output you expect? Both?

Comment: @HereticMonkey packages like html2text

Comment: @Jack any python script or package